# Add products to cart from CMS page using foreach?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I am trying to find a way to add products to cart using from a CMS page using a foreach loop which displays the list of products from a specific category. The problem is that my add to cart form will only submit one of the products to the cart.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, I've been here for hours!

I'm not sure if it is my form or if this is even possible in Magento but I'd appreciate som advice...

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-related">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Check items to add to the cart or add to your wishlist') ?>&nbsp;<br /></p>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="control-label">
                        <a class="fancybox static-thumbs pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(500, 450); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135) ?>" width="150" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    </label>

                    <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="pull-right" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" rel="tooltip"><span class="icon-check"></span></a>

<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>" method="post">
       <fieldset>
        <p class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:'); ?></p>
  <select name="qty" class="span1">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_item)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?>
</select>

            <button title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

                <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
       </fieldset>
</form>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a>


                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: It seems like you are creating a form for each product. Try moving the form out of the foreach loop. That might help solve your problem.

Comment: @dasfisch Thankyou for your response... I actually need an add to cart button 'foreach' product but at the moment I can only add one product to cart. If I take the form out of the foreach I'm not sure how I will be able to add sepearate products to the cart????

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the button to be able to add products from each of those forms with one click, correct?

Comment: @dasfisch Not quite, I would like something similar to catalog/product_list whereby a selection of products are listed from one category. I would like to be able to select a product, choose quantity and add to cart. At the moment only one product goes into the cart regardless on how many are being displayed...

Comment: see related product logic of magento, you get some idea

Comment: @mufaddal Thanks for the hint, I have a problem where I cannot add more than QTY (1) to the cart for the last product in the list. All products above it only add one product even if I have selected 5 from the dropdown list???

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work, for anyone trying to add related products on a CMS page use this code:

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-related">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Related Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Check items to add to the cart or add to your wishlist') ?>&nbsp;<br /></p>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
             <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="control-label">
                        <a class="fancybox static-thumbs pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(500, 450); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135) ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                    </label>
<div class="controls">
<label class="checkbox">
        <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="pull-right" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>" rel="tooltip"><span class="icon-check"></span></a>

<p class="product-name span6">
 <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product-title"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a>
 <br />
    <?php echo nl2br($this->getProduct()->getDescription()) ?>
</p>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>" method="post">

<fieldset>
  <label class="product-name"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity:'); ?></label>
  <select name="qty" class="span1">
  <?php $i = 1 ?>
  <?php do { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
      <?php echo $i?>
      <?php $i++ ?>
    </option>
    <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_item)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-danger"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>            
</fieldset>

</form>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
</label>

</div>
    </div>
    <hr />
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```